# Setting height of jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a jquery dialog box which contains an image (img). I am trying to set the height of the box to match the image but I am finding that both are being set smaller than I specify. For example, the following lines:

```
console.log("h1 " + $('#display').height());
$("#display").dialog('option', 'height', img.height);                               
console.log("h2 " + $('#display').height());
console.log("ih " + img.height);
```

produce the following output to the console:

```
h1 564 
h2 564 
ih 640
```

This suggests to me that $('#creativeImageDisplay').height() refers to inner height but the 'height' in the options refers to outer height. Is there any way of setting inner height (such that outer height is increased correspondingly)?

*Edit*

```
('#display').outerHeight(true) 652 
('#display').outerHeight(false) 652 
('#display')innerHeight() 652
```

Comment: refer to http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/ and http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=.height&go=

Comment: Thank you, but none of these options seem to include the title bar. I get the results which I've added in the edit above.

Comment: Does image have dynamic dimensions? Do you can simply to set height in css-file?

Comment: Several different images can be opened in the box so the height may change.

Comment: Also it can be a problem if your function binded to a 'ready' event and img does not have height specified. Try to bind function to the window.onload and see what will happen

Comment: Thanks Caligula, I encountered that exact problem a few days ago. This all happens onload so the image height is being returned correctly.

Comment: Image is outside the dialog box, right?

Comment: Post more info, especially markup

Comment: Thank you for all of your helpful comments. It turned out the problem was that I had set the image position to 'fixed' which for some reason was preventing the auto resize from working. The image was inside the dialog box btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be tidy.
Thank you for all of your helpful comments. It turned out the problem was that I had set the image position to 'fixed' which for some reason was preventing the auto resize from working.

Answer (score 0):

After you have generated your dialog, it will output something like this:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ...">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ..."> ... </div>
    <div id="display" class="ui-dialog-content ..."> ....</div>
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ..."> ... </div>
</div>
```

You could try simply `$("#display").height(im.height());` for inner height.

Comment: No joy: it has the same effect as $("#display").dialog('option', 'height', img.height);

Comment: If you need the outer height to change, you can try setting the parent, which is the containing div. `$("#display").parent().height(im.height());`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="panel">
  <input type="button" id="btndialog1" name="btndialog1" value="Show Dialogue1"/>
  &nbsp;
  <input type="button" id="btndialog2" name="btndialog2" value="Show Dialogue2"/>
  <br/>
  <div id="imgdialog1" title="Dialogue1 with Image">
    <p>
      <img src="http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/photos/image1.jpg" id="img1">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="imgdialog2" title="Dialogue2 with image">
    <p>
      <img id="img2" src="http://www.xda-developers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/android_boot_image.jpg"/>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#imgdialog1').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        'width': 'auto',
        'height': 'auto'
    });
    $('#imgdialog2').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        'width': 'auto',
        'height': 'auto'
    });
    $("#btndialog1").click(function() {
        $('#imgdialog1').dialog('open');
    });
    $("#btndialog2").click(function() {
        $('#imgdialog2').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

I have done bins, so try on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpad